# Getting NULL error

Tags: c, null

Here is my code:

```
void printlist(struct node *st) { 
  while(st != NULL); {
    printnode(st);
    st=st->next;
  }
  return;
}
```

However I'm having an error when running the prog: `parse error before;`
I don't understand where the error is.

Comment: On the assumption that `parse error before;` is an error you're getting from your compiler, this means there's an error elsewhere in your program - could you post a minimal actual program which shows the error?

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
while(st != NULL); {
```

Needs to be this:

```
while(st != NULL) {
```

The semicolon is the issue.

Comment: As @EdwinBuck has noted, this is not a parse error. It is perfectly valid C, if almost certainly not what the OP wants to do.

Comment: I just kind of assumed that the parser error is within the printnode() function and that he's passing a null node in.

Answer (score 3):

```
  while(st != NULL); {
    printnode(st);
    st=st->next;
  }
```

doesn't actually do what you think it does.  Let me format it for you

```
  while (st != NULL) ;

  {
    printnode(st);
    st=st->next;
  }
```

Which means that while st is not null, you do nothing, then you run the next block unconditionally.

Comment: Also, some include chains don't define NULL to be 0.  If you are using one of those, the correct syntax is `while (st != 0) { ... }`